# Flink streaming: Get top n of elements for each timewindow

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have tuple (Float, String) of datastream which i would like to sort and pick three largest values for each timewindow (fixed). Windowing of datastream is by processing time and sorting in natural order.

Using Flink 1.0.1, below are my try outs

```
          val topTasks = new mutable.PriorityQueue[(Float, String)](Ordering.Tuple2.reverse) //Ex:(5250, "mytask")
          //Get stream and other operations ...
          val sortMetricStream = metricStream
                       .map { metrics =>
                         topTasks.enqueue(metrics._1, metrics._2)
                       }
                       .timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(10))
                       .reduce({ (topTasks.dequeue()._2, topTasks.dequeue()._2, topTasks.dequeue()._2)
                       })
```

and

```
    val sortMetricStream = metricStream
                       .timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(10))
                       .partitionByRange(0)
                       .sortPartition(0, Order.DESCENDING)
```

in either one sortMetricStream does not give me expected tasks name.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should share your "tryouts"

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply(...)` instead of `reduce(...)` (see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/apis/streaming/index.html#datastream-transformations)

By using the iterator of `WindowFunction#apply()` you can buffer all records of the window internally (for example in a list), then sort (the list), and finally emit your result. You can call `Collector#collect()` zero, one, or multiples times.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. This would make me implement my own sort..(runtime of O(nlogn)). I was looking more like at framework level, have aggregator handle it..like max(), min()

Comment: Yes. Flink does not provide what you want, so a custom solution is right now the only way to get this done.